# my error message reads expected class, delegate, enum. interface, or struct

Tags: c#

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  class Student
  {
    private string _name;
    private int _phoneNo;
    private string _address;
    private string _occupation;
    private string _courseOfStudy;
    private  int _duration;
    private string _uploadPicture;
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get { return _name;}
    set { _name = value;}
  }

  public int PhoneNumber
  {
    get { return _phoneNo;}
    set { _phoneNo = value;}
  }

  public string Address
  {
    get { return _address;}
    set { _address = value;}
  }

  public string Occupation
  {
    get { return _occupation;}
    set { _occupation = value;}
  }

  public string CourseOfStudy
  {
    get { return _courseOfStudy;}
    set { _courseOfStudy = value;}
  }

  public int Duration
  {
    get { return _duration;}
    set { _duration = value;}
  }

  public string Uploadpicture
  {
    get { return _uploadpicture;}
    set { _uploadpicture = value;}
  }

  public Student()
  {
    _name = "";
    _phoneNo = "";
    _address = "";
     _occupation = "";
     _courseOfStudy = "";
     _duration = "";
     _uploadPicture = "";

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Called Constructor")
  }

  public Student (String name, int phoneNo, string address, string occupation, string courseOfStudy, int duration, string uploadPicture)
  {
    _name = name;
    _phoneNo = phoneNo;
    _address = address;
     _occupation = occupation;
     _courseOfStudy = courseOfStudy;
     _duration = duration;
     _uploadPicture = uploadPicture;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot declare methods outside of a class in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that first `}`

it is causing the properties below it to appear outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have put all your properties and constructors outside the class. Also you have large amounts of unnecessary code for handling the properties, as you are not encapsulating the field values in any way. So they can be rewritten to use auto properties. Try the following rewrite:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Occupation { get; set; }

        public string CourseOfStudy { get; set; }

        public int Duration { get; set; }

        public string UploadPicture { get; set; }

        public Student() : this("", 0, "", "", "", 0, "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Called Constructor");
        }

        public Student(String name, int phoneNo, string address, string occupation, string courseOfStudy, int duration, string uploadPicture)
        {
            Name = name;
            PhoneNumber = phoneNo;
            Address = address;
            Occupation = occupation;
            CourseOfStudy = courseOfStudy;
            Duration = duration;
            UploadPicture = uploadPicture;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The members are courrently not inside your class. The curly bracket behind _uploadPicture; } shuld be at the end.

Also, there a some other mistakes:

- _uploadpicture should be _uploadPicture in  public string Uploadpicture
- you are trying to initialise an int with an string (_phoneNo = "";)

Here is the corrected class:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
class Student {
    private string _name;
    private int _phoneNo;
    private string _address;
    private string _occupation;
    private string _courseOfStudy;
    private int _duration;
    private string _uploadPicture;


    public string Name {
        get {
            return _name;
        }
        set {
            _name = value;
        }
    }


    public int PhoneNumber {
        get {
            return _phoneNo;
        }
        set {
            _phoneNo = value;
        }
    }


    public string Address {
        get {
            return _address;
        }
        set {
            _address = value;
        }
    }


    public string Occupation {
        get {
            return _occupation;
        }
        set {
            _occupation = value;
        }
    }


    public string CourseOfStudy {
        get {
            return _courseOfStudy;
        }
        set {
            _courseOfStudy = value;
        }
    }


    public int Duration {
        get {
            return _duration;
        }
        set {
            _duration = value;
        }
    }

    public string Uploadpicture {
        get {
            return _uploadPicture;
        }
        set {
            _uploadPicture = value;
        }
    }


    public Student() {
        _name = "";
        _phoneNo = 0;
        _address = "";
        _occupation = "";
        _courseOfStudy = "";
        _duration = 0;
        _uploadPicture = "";

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Called Constructor");

    }

    public Student(string name, int phoneNo, string address, string occupation, string courseOfStudy, int duration, string uploadPicture) {

        _name = name;
        _phoneNo = phoneNo;
        _address = address;
        _occupation = occupation;
        _courseOfStudy = courseOfStudy;
        _duration = duration;
        _uploadPicture = uploadPicture;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why have you mangled the layout of the code so much with your answer? Your "improved" code is now unreadable compared with the original due to your {}'s use compared with the OP.

Comment: "unreadable is bit harsh, isn't it? Its the default format of Visual Studio.

Comment: It absolutely is not the default format for VS. If VS is laying code out in that style for you, then your C# language settings have been changed. The default style is as the OP laid it out.